# Make booklet into normal document

Tags: microsoft-word

I was given a booklet that was made in MS Word manually - pages are split into two columns, first sheet contains first and last page, next contains second and second-to-last and so on.

I was asked to make this sendable by e-mail. So I have to change it into normal .docx or .pdf file with first page coming first and last page coming last.

Is there any quick solutions to this - a tool to split and reorder pages?

I am afraid of manual splitting in MS Word because I'm not sure I can exactly reproduce the margins, especially in the foldable part.

Comment: Why cannot it not be sent by email in it's current state? I'm not sure exactly what you're asking but you'll most likely just have to manually modify it. If you're worried about ruining it, copy the file as a backup somewhere.

Comment: By "send by email" I mean sending so people would read it electronically not printed. It is awkward to read a document that starts with it's last page :)

Comment: If you're worried about messing up the formatting, etc., and only need it readable (not editable), turn it into page images.  For example, maximize each page on the screen and do a screen snapshot, or export the document to a multi-page image file and then cut it up in image software.  Then combine the page images in sequence.  You can paste them into a document or save the image list as a PDF.

Comment: And you still want the booklet shown in the output pdf as 2 columns per page or each column in its own page?